A string with mathematical operators (fractions, superscripts, subscripts, etc.) and a variable number
I want to create a list in Mathematica where a word contains a number that changes within it. However, I want the number to appear as a superscript or subscript or in a fraction etc. How can I do this?
More specifically, I want to automate the generation of this string.

One first (unsuccessful and ugly) attempt was the following:
nameList = Table[(Subscript["log", a]) x, {a, 2, 5}]

Result:
{x Subscript["log", 2], x Subscript["log", 3], x Subscript["log", 4], 
 x Subscript["log", 5]}


I don't fully understand what you want. If you want to have a string, you have to convert expressions to string by using ToString. For example: Table[ToString[Subscript["log", a], TraditionalForm] <> ToString[x], {a, 2, 5}]

@Domen , I just edited the question.

If you are struggling with logarithms, please see #109110. `SetSystemOptions[
"SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False];
TraditionalForm@Table[(x^a - Log[a, x])/(x + a), {a, 2, 5}]`

Another thing to try lis=Range[2,6]; SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"->"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog"->False]; (Superscript[x,#]-Log[#,x])/(x+#)&/@lis  https://i.sstatic.net/mrWxdJDs.png

@Domen I was wondering if there was a general method, not just with logarithms. In any case, the problem is solved! Thank you very much for the answer!

@Nasser Thank you very much for the answer! However, I will prefer the other solution, as it produces exactly the formatting features I wanted.

Could please provide the input with which you are starting and the output you would like to have in the final? I will help to know what has to be done.

@Rajendraprasad Input: $\frac{x^n-\log_n x}{x+n}$ and $n\in{2,3,4,5,6}$
Output: The image.

Following the information provided in reply to the comment and based on my understanding of the problem, the solution I can think of is:
 nameList = 
 Table[(Power[x, a] - Power[Subscript["log", a], x])/(x + a), {a, 2, 
   5}]


Unfortunately, with this code, the x is placed in the exponent. In fact, it is the argument of the logarithm. If I remove the Power, x is placed in front of the logarithm instead of being its argument.

Try nameList = Table[(Power[x, a] - With[{heldA = a},       HoldForm@Times[Subscript["log", heldA], x]       ])/(x + a), {a, 2, 5}]
